# Zend Calendar Zend_Gdata_App_HttpException' with message 'Expected response code 200, got 401

Tags: zend-framework

I want inteface this script with google calendar using Zend Framework.
This code works locally but doesn't works on altervista.
The error is

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Gdata_App_HttpException' with
>   message 'Expected response code 200, got 401

```
    <?php

require_once "Zend/Loader.php";

Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_AuthSub');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_Calendar');

$user = "xxx@gmail.com";
$pass = "xxxxx";
$title= "Evento ";
$content="evento presso nome associaizone";
$where="luogo";


$service = Zend_Gdata_Calendar::AUTH_SERVICE_NAME;

try {
   $client = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient($user, $pass, 'cl');
} catch (Zend_Gdata_App_CaptchaRequiredException $cre) {
    echo 'URL of CAPTCHA image: ' . $cre->getCaptchaUrl() . "\n";
    echo 'Token ID: ' . $cre->getCaptchaToken() . "\n";
} catch (Zend_Gdata_App_AuthException $ae) {
   echo 'Problem authenticating: ' . $ae->exception() . "\n";
}





$service = new Zend_Gdata_Calendar($client);

 //

 // Create a new entry using the calendar service's magic factory method
$event= $service->newEventEntry();


// Populate the event with the desired information
// Note that each attribute is crated as an instance of a matching class
$event->title = $service->newTitle($title);
$event->content= $service->newContent($content);
$event->where = array($service->newWhere($where));

// Set the date using RFC 3339 format.
$startDate = "2014-03-18";
$startTime = "14:00";
$endDate = "2014-03-19";
$endTime = "16:00";
$tzOffset = "-08";

$when = $service->newWhen();
$when->startTime = "{$startDate}T{$startTime}:00.000{$tzOffset}:00";
$when->endTime = "{$endDate}T{$endTime}:00.000{$tzOffset}:00";
$event->when = array($when);

// Upload the event to the calendar server
// A copy of the event as it is recorded on the server is returned
$newEvent = $service->insertEvent($event);


?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Zend_Gdata and ZendGData are out of maintenance.

Instead the recomendation is migrate to the official Google SDK https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/

Comment: con questo sdk posso utilizzare Google Calendar?I cannot find riht api